# Script on windows to download and restore Heroku postgres database

Tags: windows, postgresql, shell, curl, heroku-cli

I'm trying to create a script on Windows that automates the process of download and restore that I have to do from postgres database on Heroku.

I manually do:

`heroku pg:backups:download -o db_name.dump --app app_name`

But when I run it in the script (.bat), it ends when the line is executed and do not run the next lines (create a postgres db and restore it).

What can I do?
I've tryed to substitute the download command to:

```
curl -o db_name.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app app_name`
```

But i get the following errors:

[CMD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ZEm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try put the download link on any variable (link, for example) and then download (with curl) with the link, into some file. Like:

Putting the download link on variable link

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`heroku pg:backups public-url --app app_name`) DO (
SET link=%%F
)
```

Download file on path

```
curl "%link%" > C:\..\..\db_name.dump
```